How to fix a not working discordbot? java-lang
I've recently created a discord bot with the help of chatgpt in Java language. The bot is running and is online on the discord server but is not doing what i want. The purpose is to greet someone when they come online to the server. The bot is not doing that. I don't know if something is wrong within the code or if i set it up to the server incorrectly. I can mention that the bot has the permissions: (Presence Intent, Server Members Intent and Message Content Intent) enabled. I also think i have the latest versions aswell of Maven, JDA etc. I'm quite knew to coding so i believe it's logical errors but who i am to tell, please take a look and i would be grateful :)
This is my java file and pom.xml file
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.OnlineStatus;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Member;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.channel.concrete.TextChannel;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.user.update.UserUpdateOnlineStatusEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.requests.GatewayIntent;

import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;

public class OnlineTrackerBot extends ListenerAdapter
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws LoginException {
        String token = "my_token";  // Replaced with my bot token

        JDABuilder builder = JDABuilder.createDefault(token);
        builder.enableIntents(GatewayIntent.GUILD_PRESENCES, GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS, GatewayIntent.MESSAGE_CONTENT);  // Enable necessary intents
        builder.addEventListeners(new OnlineTrackerBot());
        System.out.println("Event listeners added.");
        builder.build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onUserUpdateOnlineStatus(UserUpdateOnlineStatusEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Received UserUpdateOnlineStatusEvent for user: " + event.getUser().getName());

        // Get the member whose presence updated
        Member member = event.getGuild().getMember(event.getUser());
        if (member == null) {
            System.out.println("Member not found in the guild.");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Member found: " + member.getEffectiveName());

        // Check if the member's status is now ONLINE
        if (event.getNewOnlineStatus() == OnlineStatus.ONLINE) {
            // Get the general channel (replace with your actual channel name)
            TextChannel generalChannel = event.getGuild().getTextChannelsByName("inte-dansband-förhelvete", true).get(0);

            // Send a welcome message in the general channel
            if (generalChannel != null) {
                System.out.println("Sending message to channel: " + generalChannel.getName());
                generalChannel.sendMessage("Welcome back online, " + member.getAsMention() + "!").queue();
            } else {
                System.out.println("General channel not found.");
            }
        }
    }
}

Pom.xml file
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>me.Carllundholm</groupId>
  <artifactId>OnlineTrackerBot</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>OnlineTrackerBot</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
      <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.0</version> <!-- Use a stable release of JDA -->
    </dependency>
    <!-- JUnit 5 Dependency -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>5.9.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>5.9.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.9</version>
    </dependency>

Thanks in advance!
I've tried to change different methods and versions of JDA because many times i get the message: cannot resolve symbol or cannot resolve method.

Please [edit] your question to include the complete error message.

Did you read the requirements for the event? It is in the documentation.

The problem is in the way you are creating your bot. Here's the version that would actually work:
public static JDA builder;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String token = "token";  // Replaced with my bot token

    builder  = JDABuilder.create(GatewayIntent.GUILD_PRESENCES, GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS, GatewayIntent.MESSAGE_CONTENT)
                         .setToken(token)
                         .build();
    builder.addEventListener(new OnlineTracker());
    System.out.println("Event listeners added.");
}

and for the Listener you can create it in a separate class and add it the same way as before.
It just looks more organized. You can't fit everything in one class.
Also about your Listener I see you are using
.getTextChannelsByName().get(0) while sending the message.
A better way would be using .getTextChannelById()
because .getTextChannelsByName() returns a list that might contain multiple channels with same name.
So getting them with their respective id is better.
Anyways if you face any problem now feel free to ask!
